# Index pandas dataframe by date

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to index my pandas dataframe by date by using:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df)
```

but am getting the following error:

```
    ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] 

    be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

My current pandas dataframe looks
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78EDt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert the entire dataframe. Instead, you just want to apply the function to the dataframe index.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```